# nsxmlparse Tableview Alignment

Tags: iphone, tableview

[image][image]      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@""];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.backgroundView = [[[CustomCell alloc] init] autorelease];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[CustomCell alloc] init] autorelease];

// At end of function, right before return cell:
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


// Configure the cell.
UILabel *myLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 45)];
UILabel *myLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 55, 300, 20)];
UILabel *myLabel3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 68, 300, 60)];

Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    myLabel1.text=aBook.title;
    myLabel2.text=aBook.pubDate;
    myLabel3.text=aBook.description;


//myLabel1.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
myLabel1.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
myLabel1.numberOfLines=1;
myLabel1.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
myLabel1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
myLabel1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

myLabel2.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

myLabel3.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
myLabel3.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
myLabel3.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
myLabel3.numberOfLines=3;
//myLabel3.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
myLabel3.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
myLabel3.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];



//myLabel1.shadowColor=[UIColor redColor];
//myLabel1.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel3];




    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
[myLabel1 release];
[myLabel2 release];
[myLabel3 release];
//Set up the cell

return cell;
```

guys i have these codings. in mylabel 1 if i sets to 2, the text goes down so i cant see. 
now finally i want to display 2lines of Title, 1 line of pubDate and 3 Lines of Description in one row. 
i have displayed but i need some alignment i.e. above points, it should remove HTML(&mdash) tags

i dont know hw to customizing this.struggling with this.pls help me out

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and show us what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass the UITableViewCell and use an that custom cell.

First problem here is that you add the labels each time your cell is displayed. But you may reuse some cells that all ready have in their contentView the labels so you can reuse these labels.

Second problem is the performance each time you alloc init and release 3 labels on each row is displayed. This will produce slow scroll speed on slow devices like iPhone 3G.

Take a look at apple's CustomTableViewCell [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318).

[Here](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/) is an tutorial how to subClass UITableViewCell
With an custom cell class your method will Look like this

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    [cell setLabel1String:aBook.title];
    [cell setLabel2String:aBook.pubDate];
    [cell setLabel3String:aBook.description];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You just need an custom cell Class.

Comment: if i reuse the same label, i cant get the display like some other X and Y coordinates